# How can I set new value to props in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

In parent component I have:

```
<notification-row v-for="(item, index) in notifications" :key="index" :item="item" />
```

In child component I have:

```
...
    <tr class="notification-row" :class="{ active: props.item.status !== 'readed' }">
...
```

So, in child component I need make request to change status. After this I need change it(props.item.status) in my component. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit an event from your child component

```
<button @click="$emit('someEvent')">click me</button>
```

And listen to it from the parent component

```
<MyComponent @some-event="callYourUpdateFunction" />
```

Here's some documentation about component events from the vue.js docs
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html